# Standalone hibernate and narayana JTA standalone platform

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jta

as far as I know Narayana is supposed to be a standalone JTA platform implementation that can be used with hibernate for transaction management.

I am struggling to set up a simple example on how to use this. Here's what I did so far:

```
<persistence-unit name="trackedTest" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>pandaa.test.main.MyObject</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="30" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/drools" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

MyObject is a simple Object with 1 attribute.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="testJTA")
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

And for the main, I am trying to persist just one little object:

```
public class StandaloneNaranya {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("trackedTest");

        EntityManager em = createEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        TransactionManager tm = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();

        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        o.setId("asd");

        tm.begin();

        em.persist(o);
        em.flush();

        tm.commit();

    }
}
```

This then tells me:

```
INFO: ARJUNA012170: TransactionStatusManager started on port 49231 and host 127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:993)
    at pandaa.test.main.StandaloneNaranya.main(StandaloneNaranya.java:26)
```

I have no idea how to set this up correctly. Running in a container is not an option for me. Any help would be great.

Comment: I though that is what tm.begin() does. I can not call em.getTransaction().begin() since I want it to be handled by jta

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that line. Does it make any difference if you create `EntityManager` after you start the transaction?

Comment: if you are using a JTA provider then you need to get the UserTransaction and call begin on that. Are you? I don't see any attempt to get the JTA transaction in your main()

Comment: I didn't, however more testing has shown me, that I need to call begin() and then call joinTransaction() on the EM for this to work... I have no idea why, it all makes no sense to me. What do you mean by JTA Provider? Like an EE container? I don't use that. I wanted it to be standalone and as thin as possible (frankly, if drools didn't require JTA, i wouldn't use it at all). Edit: Debug shows, that begin() on the TM as shown in the code will create a usertransaction if there is none. So begin on TM seems to be delegating to the UserTransaction as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [docs for DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/transactions.html#jta) with a standalone JTA provider. I'd expect to see a `<jta-data-source>` in your *persistence.xml* as a start.
The key parts of the runtime code are that you need to get the UserTransaction from the JTA provider, something like this (adapt your JNDI to suit where you have it)

```
UserTransaction ut = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
```

and then

```
ut.begin();

{your JPA code}

ut.commit();
```

Ought to be possible to get a working solution using this style with any JPA provider. There is an example of `em.joinTransaction` in that link dependent on when you start the JTA transaction.

Comment: Some nice examples in there that helped me. I managed to get it to work with narayana too. My issue was the whole jndi lookup was messed up and not correct, so the internal jboss classes could never find the correct implementations. Thanks!